# How to use sass instead of style.css in umbraco cms without installing the package?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, sass, umbraco, umbraco7

How to use **sass** instead of **style.css** in Umbraco CMS without installing the package ?

Comment: That doesn't actually make sense. Sass is a preprocessor. The style.css will always be what you'll use on a website. Google around and learn about sass and css and the differences. 

Also, which package are you talking about exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To use Sass you must **compile** it into **css** so everyone can use it. I presume this "package" you mention compiles your sass into css.

You can edit sass in the Umbraco CMS but don't expect it to compile to css without a package.

I suggest writing your sass in a file editor on your **local machine** and compile it to CSS. Then copy the CSS into the back office. You will need to install Sass first: https://sass-lang.com/install